# Remove repeated rows in 2D numpy array, maintaining first instance and ordering

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I have an 2-dimensional Numpy array where some rows are not unique, i.e., when I do:

```
import numpy as np

data.shape                        #number of rows X columns in data
# (75000, 8)

np.unique(data.T, axis=0).shape   #number of unique rows is fewer than above
# (74801, 8)
```

Starting with the first row of `data`, **I would like to remove any row that is a duplicate of a previous row**, maintaining the original order of the rows. In the above example, the final shape of the new Numpy array should be (74801, 8).

E.g., given the below data array

```
data = np.array([[1,2,1],[2,2,3],[3,3,2],[2,2,3],[1,1,2],[0,0,0],[3,3,2]])
print(data)
[[1 2 1]
 [2 2 3]
 [3 3 2]
 [2 2 3]
 [1 1 2]
 [0 0 0]
 [3 3 2]]
```

I'd like to have the unique rows in their **original order**, i.e.,

```
[[1 2 1]
 [2 2 3]
 [3 3 2]
 [1 1 2]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Any tips on an efficient solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the "return_index" parameter:

```
data[np.sort(np.unique(data, axis = 0, return_index = True)[1])]
```

As it name indicates, it will return the unique rows and their indices in that order inside a tuple (that's why there's a `[1]` at the end).

---

You can also use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates().values
```